# Pagination and filtering on ICollectionView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, pagination, filtering

I have a large amount of data in ObservableCollection, which is bound to DataGrid through ICollectionView layer as follows:

```
public ICollectionView ProductsCollectionView
        {
            get { return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Products); }
            set { NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductsCollectionView"); refreshCollection(); }
        }
```

I want to allow users to filter this data with a search string, this part works well as follows:

```
ProductsCollectionView.Filter += new Predicate<object>(filterProduct);
```

I also want to add pagination functionality to improve performance of my app but I can't figure out how to combine both of those functionalities. I have tried adding an extra filter to this collection which would handle pagination as follows:

```
ProductsCollectionView.Filter += new Predicate<object>(filterPages);
```

but it gives unexpected results when the second filter is applied.

I have also tried binding to ObservableCollection instead and reinitiating it with LINQ expression every time filtering occurs, but I could not get UI updated accordingly:

```
public ObservableCollection<ProductModel> Products 
{
    get 
    {
        return products;
    }
    set 
    { 
        if(products != value)
        {
            products = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Products");
        }
    }
}
public ProductViewModel()
{      
        Products = db.GetProducts.Where(filterProduct).Skip(Start).Take(ItemCount).ToList();
}
```

I tried doing the same on getter of ICollectionView too.

I have also tried combining both of the filters in one and applying it on ICollectionView, it worked, but performance became even worse this way:

```
        public bool filterProduct(object obj)
        {
            var data = obj as ProductModel;
            bool isAdded = false;
            bool toReturn = false;

            //SearchString filtering
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                isAdded = data.Name.ToString().Contains(searchString)
            }
            else
            {
                isAdded = true;
            }

            //Beginning of pagination
            if (CounterProducts == Products.Count)
            {
                CounterProducts = 0; //Counts how many products have been filtered
                CounterAdded = 0; //Counts how many products passed the string filtering
            }
            CounterProducts++;

            //Check result of searchString filtering
            if (isAdded)
            {
                CounterAdded++;
            }

            //Determine right current page
            int workingPage = 1;
            if (previousSearchString == SearchString)
            {
                workingPage = CurrentPage;
            }

            //Pagination
            if (CounterAdded > ItemsPerPage * (workingPage - 1) && CounterAdded <= (ItemsPerPage * workingPage) && isAdded)
            {
                toReturn = true;
            }

            //Last item
            if (CounterProducts == Products.Count)
            {
                previousSearchString = SearchString;
                if (CounterAdded % ItemsPerPage > 0)
                {
                    TotalPages = (CounterAdded / ItemsPerPage) + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    TotalPages = CounterAdded / ItemsPerPage;
                }
            }

            return toReturn;
        }
```

**I also need to update objects in the collection on runtime**, so IEnumerable solutions might not be the best fit here (or i might be wrong?).

I have tried some other ways too, but I think this question is long enough already. Now I am looking for any advice or a good approach to achieve both filtering on a string and pagination for bound data collection. Any input is highly appreciated. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You can look at the paging collection view for Silverlight here: https://github.com/microsoftarchive/SilverlightToolkit/tree/master/Release/Silverlight3/Source/System.Windows.Data/PagedCollectionView. I used it a long time ago and worked in WPF without much trouble.

Comment: @Tom thanks for the advice, but I am receiving the following exception when trying to initialize this collection `System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  
Make sure "System.Windows.Data.PagedCollectionView.PagedCollectionViewResources.resources" 
was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "MyApp" at compile time, 
or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.`

Are you sure it is not outdated?

Comment: It is outdated, it's eleven years old :) But it should work, I used it 2-3 years ago. There is a PagedCollectionViewResources.resx file there and you should set a build action (right click | Properties) to Embedded Resource.

Comment: @Tom yea, its exactly how I got it in the properties, however, the exception still occurs. What else could go wrong?

Comment: See my answer. HTH, Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `PagingCollectionView` for Silverlight here: https://github.com/microsoftarchive/SilverlightToolkit/tree/master/Release/Silverlight3/Source/System.Windows.Data/PagedCollectionView

The build action for the resource file `PagedCollectionViewResources.resx` should be Embedded resource.

You should also fix a resource name in `PagedCollectionViewResources` class (it's in the `PagedCollectionViewResources.Designer.cs` file). It should have a full namespace of the resource file.

For example, I have a dll called `Library.Wpf`. Paging stuff is in the directory `Paging`, and the resource file is in that directory.

```
> Library.Wpf
  … other stuff
  > Paging
    … other files 
     > PagedCollectionViewResources.resx
       > PagedCollectionViewResources.Designer.cs
```

and my `ResourceManager` property is like this:

```
internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
    get {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
            global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Library.Wpf.Paging.PagedCollectionViewResources", typeof(PagedCollectionViewResources).Assembly);
            resourceMan = temp;
            }
        return resourceMan;
        }
    }
```

I cannot test whether it works, but it compiles without error.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! It indeed compiled and I got filtering and paging working. It's awesome, thank you very much! However, I'm struggling to do any changes within the collection (add, delete, edit item). AddNew and RemoveAt throw exceptions saying that the collection is of a fixed size, while EditItem seems to be actually adding a new item. Do you know what could I be doing wrong?
For example, this is how I add:
            `ProductModel product = PagedCollectionView.AddNew() as ProductModel;
            product.Name = "newProduct";
            PagedCollectionView.CommitNew();`

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I just tried this a few years ago, but didn't actually used it in any real project. But, since PagedCollectionView wraps an IEnumerable source parameter, you should see what is the type of collection wrapped in PagedCollectionView and if it has IsFixedSize property set. For example, in the simple List<T> this should be false. See here (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs)

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, I initialized PagedCollectionView with IEnumerable, this is why I was getting those exceptions. If I pass List in the constructor - everything works like a charm. So thanks a lot for your help, I will mark your answer as a solution. By the way, do you by any chance know an easy way to create an 
interactive pagination UI (buttons like first page, last page and all the pages in between). Thanks a lot for your help again!

Comment: There is a DataPager control in there somewhere, try with this.